# Flash - Multi user environment, each having different settings, load them so others can see?

Tags: php, mysql, flash, actionscript

I am complete newbie to flash but I am learning it now.
The situation is:
I have a small game (models, animations, sounds done already, scripting left).
It's a shooting game which is hosted on website and multiple users who play it see each other in game and can shoot each other - each user can customize their character looks, so it must remember it and save it to MySQL database.

So basically each user sees other users and their gear setups.

I am completely lost as to where to start, could you please give some directions of what I should start learning?

Note: I know PHP, MySQL, JS, C#, Java but not ActionScript (assuming that's what kicks in here).

Where should I start? how will it load each users gear/content?

Comment: you say you have this game ... then you say you dont know where to start ? did you build the game yet ?

Comment: I have all the content for it, but I need to tie it together with script. I have animations, characters, gear drawn

Comment: So how you will develop a multi player game in Java or C#?

Comment: Well can it be run on flash?

Comment: No, what I meant is if you don't know how to make the game then it is better to learn that first, how the games are made, stuff like that?

Comment: I used Unity before, and Unreal Engine and scripted game bits in it before, but I am completely new to flash